# unknown value in Codeigniter session query

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need help with this session problem that I am not able to solve.

I have this controller

```
function update_listing_id() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    $username = $this->session->userdata('v_member_username');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->my_listings_model->keep_property_id_in_session($id);
    $this->load->view('view');
```

in model

```
public function keep_property_id_in_session($id) {
    if($id) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('property_id', $id);
        return $id;
    }
    elseif($this->session->userdata('property_id')) {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('property_id');
        return $id;
    } else {
        $id ="";
        return $id;
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass this id in session to another function like this

```
public function change_location() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    $username = $this->session->userdata('v_member_username');
    $id = $this->my_listings_model->keep_property_id_in_session($this->session->userdata('property_id'));
    //$id = $this->session->userdata('property_id'); Either this

    $this->load->view('view');
```

NOW THE PROBLEM STARTS..

This session variable $id echo word "images". I have no idea where that comes from.

If I do `echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); die;` it shows:

```
Array
  (
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1453749373
    [v_member_username] => decent_dev
    [is_logged_in] => 1
    [property_id] => images
  )
```

Comment: @Abdulla.. that would be really long code, about 900 rows.. Could you suggest me what should I specifically look for? And how to unset that one only?

Comment: show me your session setting part

Comment: U r getting images from $id = $this->uri->segment(3); it should be 4.... or show yur full url

Comment: What is yur url plz show

Comment: Thanks, url is : `http://localhost/admin/dashboard/update-listing-id/43`

Comment: @Abdulla, one of it is in model mentioned above.. I am sorry I am new.. Would there be some other in config?

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner before set session is there any thing you set already ?? or is this you set first

Comment: okay, I have `if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){` before setting property id in session..

Comment: before that line clear all session and then add

Comment: Did try try print_r in both function??? U r setting twice.. but I hope this is not an issue.. @abdulla is right try to unset session and reset

Comment: I apologize couldn't do that.. is there a way that I can unset all data except logged in data, so that user won't logout..

Comment: But I suggest before unset... test like that.. chk session before calling and after calling this function keep_property_id_in_session... and also var_dump ($id);

Comment: It does echo & print_r in set_userdata function like '43'.. and string(2) "43" if vardump... But in second function doesnt.. May be it taking it from url in the first function

Comment: If u not use yur second function session is working fine chk????

Comment: Yes.. But I am not sure if in first function its printing the id from session or url itself.. Because it doesn't do the same in second function

Comment: In second fuction ist of chk what r u gettig in $this->session->userdata('property_id') by echo than call the function if property id already set no need to call function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101623/discussion-between-codeigniter-learner-and-devpro).